# Invalid redirect_uri IdentityServer4 and AppAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, appauth

I'm using the IdentityServer template that comes with asp.net core 3.1. So far so good, the SPA app works with the implicit flow. Now I have a mobile application that I want to use with the same identity server.

So in **appsettings.json** i added a new key **charla-mobile**, and set the Profile to **NativeApp**, assuming i can use my own configuration as per https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/62c098bc170f50feca15916e81cb7f321ffc52ff/src/Identity/ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer/src/Configuration/ConfigureClients.cs#L56:

```
   "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    },     
    "Clients": {
        "Charla": {
            "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
        },
        "charla-mobile": {
          "Enabled": true,
          "Profile": "NativeApp",
          "ClientName": "Charla Mobile Client (Code with PKCE)",
          "RequireClientSecret" : false,  
          "RedirectUris": ["http://localhost:8100/implicit/authcallback", "com.appauth.demo://callback"],
          "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "code", "implicit" ],
          "RequirePkce": true,
          "AllowedScopes": ["converse-appAPI", "openid", "profile"]
          
        }
    }
    
  }
```

Problem is i keep getting Invalid redirect_uri although im calling it from the javascript library with the same url (http://localhost:8100/implicit/authcallback):

```
Invalid redirect_uri: http: //localhost:8100/implicit/authcallback
    {
        "ClientId": "charla-mobile",
        "ClientName": "charla-mobile",
        "RedirectUri": null,
        "AllowedRedirectUris": ["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"],
        "SubjectId": "anonymous",
        "ResponseType": null,
        "ResponseMode": null,
        "GrantType": null,
        "RequestedScopes": "",
        "State": null,
        "UiLocales": null,
        "Nonce": null,
        "AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses": null,
        "DisplayMode": null,
        "PromptMode": null,
        "MaxAge": null,
        "LoginHint": null,
        "SessionId": null,
        "Raw": {
            "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8100/implicit/authcallback",
            "client_id": "charla-mobile",
            "response_type": "code",
            "state": "4qtaYswLFK",
            "scope": "converse-appAPI openid profile",
            "code_challenge": "opKV8gSVV5X7pQ7eTvQ3Lp40A7BXplkz4RiGkEFgBcc",
            "code_challenge_method": "S256"
        },
        "$type": "AuthorizeRequestValidationLog"
    }
```

and from chrome network tab:
[image]

**Full log as requested**

```
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[18:38:49 DBG] CORS request made for path: /.well-known/openid-configuration from origin: http://localhost:8100
[18:38:49 DBG] CorsPolicyService allowed origin: http://localhost:8100
[18:38:49 DBG] Login Url: /auth/login
[18:38:49 DBG] Login Return Url Parameter: ReturnUrl
[18:38:49 DBG] Logout Url: /Identity/Account/Logout
[18:38:49 DBG] ConsentUrl Url: /consent
[18:38:49 DBG] Consent Return Url Parameter: returnUrl
[18:38:49 DBG] Error Url: /home/error
[18:38:49 DBG] Error Id Parameter: errorId
[18:38:49 DBG] Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration matched to endpoint type Discovery
[18:38:49 DBG] Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint
[18:38:49 INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration
[18:38:49 DBG] Start discovery request
[18:38:49 DBG] Request path /connect/authorize matched to endpoint type Authorize
[18:38:49 DBG] Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
[18:38:49 INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
[18:38:49 DBG] Start authorize request
[18:38:49 DBG] No user present in authorize request
[18:38:49 DBG] Start authorize request protocol validation
[18:38:49 DBG] client configuration validation for client charla-mobile succeeded.
[18:38:49 ERR] Invalid redirect_uri: http://localhost:8100/implicit/authcallback
{"ClientId": "charla-mobile", "ClientName": "charla-mobile", "RedirectUri": null, "AllowedRedirectUris": ["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"], "SubjectId": "anonymous", "ResponseType": null, "ResponseMode": null, "GrantType": null, "RequestedScopes": "", "State": null, "UiLocales": null, "Nonce": null, "AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses": null, "DisplayMode": null, "PromptMode": null, "MaxAge": null, "LoginHint": null, "SessionId": null, "Raw": {"redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8100/implicit/authcallback", "client_id": "charla-mobile", "response_type": "code", "state": "G0Zn5uV8K4", "scope": "converse-appAPI openid profile", "code_challenge": "7vnsRsZRIzgf7Ti_gH-k1LY6fErlLZNrbfZlbQYCz7U", "code_challenge_method": "S256"}, "$type": "AuthorizeRequestValidationLog"}
[18:38:49 ERR] Request validation failed
[18:38:49 INF] {"ClientId": "charla-mobile", "ClientName": "charla-mobile", "RedirectUri": null, "AllowedRedirectUris": ["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"], "SubjectId": "anonymous", "ResponseType": null, "ResponseMode": null, "GrantType": null, "RequestedScopes": "", "State": null, "UiLocales": null, "Nonce": null, "AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses": null, "DisplayMode": null, "PromptMode": null, "MaxAge": null, "LoginHint": null, "SessionId":
null, "Raw": {"redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8100/implicit/authcallback", "client_id": "charla-mobile", "response_type": "code", "state": "G0Zn5uV8K4", "scope": "converse-appAPI openid profile", "code_challenge": "7vnsRsZRIzgf7Ti_gH-k1LY6fErlLZNrbfZlbQYCz7U", "code_challenge_method": "S256"}, "$type": "AuthorizeRequestValidationLog"}
[18:38:49 INF] {"ClientId": "charla-mobile", "ClientName": "charla-mobile", "RedirectUri": null, "Endpoint": "Authorize", "SubjectId": null, "Scopes": "", "GrantType": null, "Error": "unauthorized_client", "ErrorDescription": "Invalid redirect_uri", "Category": "Token", "Name": "Token Issued Failure", "EventType": "Failure", "Id": 2001, "Message": null, "ActivityId": "0HM1T9FDQAMOT:00000001", "TimeStamp": "2020-08-10T16:38:49.0000000Z", "ProcessId": 13112, "LocalIpAddress": "::1:5000", "RemoteIpAddress": "::1", "$type": "TokenIssuedFailureEvent"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly set redirect\_uri in Flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63816482/how-to-correctly-set-redirect-uri-in-flutter-app)

Answer (score 0):

I think its easier to configure clients in code to make sure you get it all correct. What I am thinking about is if you have missed the ClientID and if the clientID is wrong then IS can't find the correct redirectURL?

I found this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60347813/is-there-a-way-to-use-identity-server-features-in-asp-net-core-3-1-rest-api)

```
"IdentityServer": {
  "IssuerUri": "urn:sso.company.com",
  "Clients": [
    {
      "Enabled": true,
      "ClientId": "local-dev",
      "ClientName": "Local Development",
      "ClientSecrets": [ { "Value": "<Insert Sha256 hash of the secret encoded as Base64 string>" } ],
      "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "implicit" ],
      "AllowedScopes": [ "openid", "profile" ],
      "RedirectUris": [ "https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc" ],
      "RequireConsent": false
    }
  ]
```

Comment: I added the clientid, but still got the same error, but what I understand from their code https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/62c098bc170f50feca15916e81cb7f321ffc52ff/src/Identity/ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer/src/Configuration/ConfigureClients.cs#L39, they parse is as a dictionnary, not an array, so presumably the structure I have is valid

Comment: I think you also should clarify the question a bit because you are talking about both a mobile and a JavaScript application.... what does the request look like from the mobile? Also, I don't see a Nonce field in he initial request to IdentityServer.

Comment: I added the full logs to the question, the mobile application is using Ionic and Capacitor, so its basically a webview. The screenshot I attached is from chrome running this webview using `ionic serve`.

Comment: I still would recommend you to do the client config in code, just to make sure you don't get any odd JSON typo into the mix.   Then when it works in code, you can replicate it back to JSON.    One thought though, its not that you have defined charla-mobile twice? both in code and in appsettings?

Comment: nop it's all the appsettings.json. I gave it a try but it didnt work.The part in Startup.cs is Microsoft extension `            services.AddIdentityServer(SetupIdentityServer)
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ConverseContext>();
`

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer i was looking for, but I had to ditch the ApiAuthorizaion extension provided by asp.net core, and start configuring identity server using their standard documentation and configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, the solution for me was to set it up manually through code (like really manually) otherwise the redirectUri was set to a completely different value:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, AuthorizationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.Clients.AddNativeApp(
                    "MyApp", 
                    app => app
                        .WithScopes("MyServerAPI", "openid", "profile", "offline_access")
                );
                var client = options.Clients.Single(c => c.ClientId == "MyApp");
                client.AllowOfflineAccess = true;
                client.RedirectUris.Clear();
                client.RedirectUris.Add("http://localhost:4000/");
                client.PostLogoutRedirectUris.Clear();
                client.PostLogoutRedirectUris.Add("http://localhost:4000/");
                
            });
```